# How to get sum of values from two rows and assign it to the rows itself pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the sum of the n row in looping + 1, for example, in the dataset below:

```
     x    y    z
0    2    3    4
1    5    6    7
2    8    9    10
3    11   12   0
```

What i need is to sum the values of row 0 and 1, and assign it to the row 0 itself, sum values from row 1 and 2 and assign it to row 1, values from row 2 and 3 and assign it to 2, and row 3 keeps its values.
The result df would be:

```
     x    y    z
0    7    9    11
1    13   15   17
2    19   21   10
3    11   12   0
```

Imagine i have a lot of rows, like 10k and need to do it generically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with invert order of rows by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[::-1].rolling(2, min_periods=0).sum().iloc[::-1]
print (df)
      x     y     z
0   7.0   9.0  11.0
1  13.0  15.0  17.0
2  19.0  21.0  10.0
3  11.0  12.0   0.0
```

Comment: @yatu - Hmm, why do you think so? This parameter is used rare :(, so not idea if use it or not

Comment: i misconfused what i needed, i need the sum not the mean of the values

Comment: Aggregating with `sum` instead of `mean` is all @yyz_vanvlet

Comment: I think I missunderstood what it does. Shame you can't aggregate at different points in the window+

Comment: and if i wanted just the sum of values for x and y, and keep the originals values in z?